# Rest of the file not processed

Tags: google-bigquery

The status is shown as success but the file is not actually transferred to big-query.

```
# bq show -j abc

  Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration   Bytes Processed  
 ---------- --------- ----------------- ---------- ----------------- 
  load       SUCCESS   05 Jul 15:32:45   0:26:24
```

From web interface, I can see the actual error.

```
Line:9732968, Too few columns: expected 27 column(s) but got 9 column(s)
Line:10893908 / Field:1, Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered. Rest of file not processed.
```

1) How do I know which bad character needs to be removed?

2) Why does "success" shown as job status?

**Update:**

Job ID: summary_2012_07_09_to_2012_07_10a2

The error that I got at command prompt:
BigQuery error in load operation: Backend Error

A lot of lines were not processed at all. The details from web interface:

Line:9857286 / Field:1, Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered: field starts with: <15>

Line:9857287 / Field:1, Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered. Rest of file not processed.

---

All the lines where successfully processed in the second attempt:

job_id: summary_2012_07_09_to_2012_07_**10a3**

**Update 2:**

Line:174952407 / Field:1, Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered. Rest of file not processed.

Job ID: job_19890847cbc3410495c3cecaf79b31fb

Comment: Can you send the job id of the job that returned successful but the data was not actually added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the slow response, the holiday weekend meant most of the bigquery team was not answering support questions. The 'bad character' looks like it may be a known bug with some gzipped files where we improperly detect an ascii 0 value at the end of the file.

If the job is actually failing but reporting success, that sounds like a problem but we'll need the job id of the failing job in order to be able to debug. Also if you can reproduce it that would be helpful since we may not have the logs around for the original job anymore.

Comment: It fails at the end of the file, so I guess this error can be ignored.